# $ ember serve node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

```
$ ember serve
node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`
```

tried changing the node,ember and cordova versions

```
$ npm install -g node-modules
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated hawk@1.0.0: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated sntp@0.2.4: This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@0.2.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@0.9.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated boom@0.4.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest object-keys
C:\Users\vinod raj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-modules -> C:\Users\vinod raj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-modules\app.js
C:\Users\vinod raj\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- node-modules@1.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message `node_modules appears empty, you may need to run npm install` thrown by Ember CLI indicates that you haven't installed project's dependencies. You should do so by running `npm install` (or `yarn install` if you use the alternative package manager).

You run `npm install -g node-modules`. This installs a package called `node-modules` globally. This is not what you want. You want to install the project dependencies locally as specified in `package.json` and maybe locked to a specific version in a `package-lock.json` (or `yarn.lock` if using yarn).

Answer (score 0):

As @jelhan suggested you need to install dependencies via `npm` or `yarn`. In case you've done what @jelhan suggested and you're still getting the error, try removing `node_modules`, `dist` and `temp` folders and install dependencies.

```js
cd /path/to/project
rm -rf node_modules dist tmp
npm install
```